# Google VM instance transferring files using the gcloud command-line tool

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I have a website and I want to send a backup file to a my Google VM server on Google Cloud.

At first I thought of using php and curl script but a minute before I started working on it I saw on [google site](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#transfergcloud) that it is possible to send a file to google vm by gcloud I thought it was a good and simple solution, but when trying to work according to the directory I encountered a strange problem that I found no Answer.

When I try to run the following code:

```
gcloud compute scp /root/mivzakim.php jtube-get-youtube-1:~
```

I get this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.start-iap-tunnel) Python version 2.7.6 does not support SSL/TLS SNI needed for certificate verification on WebSocket connection.
>   ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
>   lost connection
>   ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [ 1].

I couldn't understand the connection to Python and I couldn't quite understand the meaning of this error,

if anyone could help me, he would be blessed :) Thank you!

Comment: What is the CLI version? `gcloud --version`. The current version is 287. To update `gcloud components update` from an elevated prompt (Windows) or use `sudo` for Linux.

Comment: @JohnHanley Google Cloud SDK 287.0.0 I tryed update but it not help

Comment: Version 287 requires Python 2.7.9+ or Python 3.5 thru 3.7. Update your Python installation.

Comment: @JohnHanley I using ubuntu server wich python are u mean?I think  I'v not python on the server

Comment: Whatever OS you are running the CLI `gcloud` on needs a newer version of Python. The documentation requires a newer version and the error message indicates the same.

Comment: @JohnHanley ok thank u so what the command for update python?

Comment: Use Google search. The answer depends on the OS you are using and how the original Python package was installed.

Comment: @JohnHanley hi! I updated and when I run python --version I see: Python 3.6.8
but google cloud still show " Python version 2.7.6 does not support SSL/TLS SNI"

Comment: You need to update Python 2.x as that is what `gcloud` is configured for. You keep leaving out details such as OS, version, etc. I can only generalize my answers.

Comment: This link will help you switch the CLI to Python 3.x: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/startup

Comment: This is just another option. Use can use browser client and it supports download/upload to/from vm.